# How to stop angular from creating multiple instances of a controller every time we use $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, electron, addeventlistener, angular-controller

I am using UI router for angular routing. Everytime $state.go() is called a new instance of the controller is being created. I have $rootScope events here. So everytime I want to print any log (using console.log()) or trigger the event from outside the controller it is executing multiple times i.e. the same number of time as the instances of the controller. How can I resolve this issue? I want the execute only one time. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks for answer in advance.
code snippet.

```
    $rootScope.$on('connect_device',function () {
        connect_device($rootScope.mac_address,$rootScope.device_name);    
    });
```

From the different controller I am emitting.

```
$rootScope.$emit("connect_device")
```

Comment: Can you provide your code please?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some `destroy`handling on your controller instance.
The events sunscribed to the `$rootScope` have to be unsubscribed upon destroy. The controller are indeed created on `$state.go`, and your eventlistereners are attached each controller creation phase. Not destroying these eventlisteners will cause such behaviour.

Please see following sample code to indicate how you can solve your problem.

```
angular.module('moduleName')
   .controller('controllerName', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function ($rootScope, $scope) {

    var cleanUpFunc = $rootScope.$on('eventName', function {
        // listener actions
    });

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        cleanUpFunc();
    });

}]);
```

By calling cleanUpFunc() in $destroy, your event listener for the `eventName` event will be un-subscribed and you will no longer be leaking memory when your controller gets cleaned up.

When there is no destroyment of events, even when the controller is already destroyed, the eventlisteners will still be active. And as a possible result you will notice that this can invokes multiple functions upon one event.

Off course without any real code examples, the following illustrates how you have to deal with `events` upon controller `destroy`.

Comment: Thanks daan.desmedt for answer. I tried the method but the issue is not resolved. The event is still triggering twice when i come to same page again.

Comment: Can you share some code? It's hard to resolve by not seeing any relevant code. How sure are you about the events being destroyed? Maybe work with some `console.logs` to see if the destroyed controller still handles a event listener.